# Is it possible to query a view with an array of keys which are in turn arrays?

Tags: couchdb

I have a requirement where in there are 3 different fields in a document, ie id, l1ser(multi-values), l2ser(multi-valued).
The UI needs to display the l2ser belonging to the particular l1ser for a particular id,(the user can select multiple l1ser and all the l2ser associated with all of the l1ser should be listed)
For instance,

l1ser : school, l2ser : staffs,students,classrooms
l1ser : IT company, l2ser : cisco, anz,cts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keys` query parameter for fetching multiple view results at once. Details can be found [in the CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=keys).

It depends on the view however if this is the correct solution. If you provide some correct JSON documents and your view code, I'll take a closer look.